# get a file from a webdav directory with XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, xmlhttprequest, webdav

i want to read text of a pdf with javascript. the pdf is saved in a webdav directory (so you have to call it with https:// not file:///?!). i tried it with XMLHttpRequest(). If i tried to load a local file it failed completely. And if i tried to load the file from the webdav there was 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing. Is there any possibility to get the single pdf from the webdav? i read about cors and this error but there wasnt something what solve my problem.

Someone who know how i get the file?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If your JS is on the same domain (origin) e.g. you fetching the file from your site then you don't need CORS. But if you wish to download/get the file feom other website thalen that site should allow it with CORS.
The CORS headers are not so easy to configure and you have to read docs.
Also please note that your site and destination should use https because requests from plain http will be blocked by a browser to avoid insecure leaks.

You can fetch the file with just GET https://example.com/ file.pdf as a usual. The WebDAV by itself only adds PROPFIND to list files in a directory and MKCOL to create a directory plus COPY/MOVE.

Also please note that PDF is a binary format and you need for some JS library to parse it